# Command not found error in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing command in bash script as:-

```
${SSH} ${USER}@${HOST} mkdir -p ${DEST_LOG_DIR};
```

However on Debug flow I get as:

```
 + 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -i xxxxx.pem user@host 'mkdir -p test"
./test.sh: line 454: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no: command not found
```

The varibable SSH is defined as

```
SSH="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

Why it is giving me this error?

Comment: Please post the _exact_ thing you have in your script (including all quotes) and the exact log, what you posted doesn't match.

Comment: You're not giving us the full picture: you obviously missed some quotes in your question.

Comment: It works here no problem. Are you sure you are using bash ???

Answer (score 2):

["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
SSH=(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no)
 ...
"${SSH[@]}" ...
```